# Link to add icon on android desktop

Tags: android, html, web

Assume that I have website `http://example.com`. Now I want to add there some link like 'Add do desktop' which will put icon with link to website on android/ios desktop. Is it even possible or user is supposed to add it manually?

Comment: Adding a link is a bit of a pain. You user could do it by following the guide here http://philwilson.org/blog/2010/01/adding-a-bookmark-to-an-android-home-screen but as for doing it in html I think it would be a security risk if that were allowed.